# How to set an image in html and bootstrap 5 with an if statement?

Tags: laravel

I have a table in html and in one row I want to place an image or icons (I still don´t know, because I want to put an assesment with the five stars and I don´t know whether it´s better an image or icon).

Here´s my table:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead style="background-color:#9ED5C5">
              <tr>
                <th>Asignatura</th>
                <th>Hora inicio</th>
                <th>Hora final</th>
                <th>Porcentaje tranquilo movimiento</th>
                <th>Porcentaje tranquilo ritmo</th>
                <th>Valoración</th>
                
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($datosClase as $datoClase)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{$asignaturas[$loop->index]['name']}}</th>
                    <th>{{$periodos[$loop->index]['time']}}</th>
                    <th>{{$periodos[$loop->index]['timeFinish']}}</th>
                    <th>{{($datoClase->total_calmado_movimiento/$datoClase->total_intervalos_movimiento)*100}}</th>
                    <th>{{($datoClase->total_calmado_ritmo/$datoClase->total_intervalos_ritmo)*100}}</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

And the thing is that in row "Valoración" I want to put the image or the icon but depending on these two values: $datoClase->`total_calmado_movimiento/$datoClase->total_intervalos_movimiento)*100` and `$datoClase->total_calmado_ritmo/$datoClase->total_intervalos_ritmo)*100`
For example: if the first element>80 and the second element>90 I will put an image or an icon with 5 stars. If both are below 30 I will place an image or an icon of 2 stars. But I don´t know very well how to do that. Thank you.

EDIT

```
<th>
@if ((($datoClase->total_calmado_movimiento/$datoClase->total_intervalos_movimiento)*100)>80 && (($datoClase->total_calmado_ritmo/$datoClase->total_intervalos_ritmo)*100)>80 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/5StarsImage.png') }}">
@elseif ((($datoClase->total_calmado_movimiento/$datoClase->total_intervalos_movimiento)*100)<30 && (($datoClase->total_calmado_ritmo/$datoClase->total_intervalos_ritmo)*100)<30 )
    <img src="{{ asset('img/"2StarsImage.png') }}">
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('img/"1StarsImage.png') }}">
@endif
</th>
```

Comment: neither an HTML nor a Bootstrap question. Is a question for JS or the framework you use

Comment: @tacoshy I use laravel. i have edited the tags in the question

Comment: You can use [If Statements](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#if-statements) in Laravel Blade.

Comment: Thanks @brombeer I have edited my question to show you if it´d be like that. And thank you again.

Comment: `'img/"2StarsImage.png'` and `'img/"1StarsImage.png'` look a little strange. Other than that, have you tried it? Does it work? Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: Yes@brombeer. It works. If you put the comment as an answer I can give a a good score and set it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note @LuisDaniels that on your edit, the first if statement and the second condition, the value is `> 80` and should be `> 90`. Plus, you are repeating the same operation over on the statements you should use a `$variable` on the view with the help of [raw php](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#raw-php) to clean the if statement and perform better. DRY: don't repeat yourself.

My suggestion:

```
<th>
    @php
        $t_movimiento = ($datoClase->total_calmado_movimiento / $datoClase->total_intervalos_movimiento) * 100;
        $t_ritmo = ($datoClase->total_calmado_ritmo / $datoClase->total_intervalos_ritmo) * 100;
    @endphp

    @if ( $t_movimiento > 80 && $t_ritmo > 90 )
        <img src="{{ asset('img/5StarsImage.png') }}">
    @elseif ( $t_movimiento < 30 && $t_ritmo < 30 )
        <img src="{{ asset('img/"2StarsImage.png') }}">
    @else
        <img src="{{ asset('img/"1StarsImage.png') }}">
    @endif
</th>
```